# How to interpret the output of a multinomial classification model in R package gbm

Tags: r, categorical-data, prediction, multinomial-distribution, boosting

After running a gradient boosted model with `n` data points using multinomial regression where the response variable (a factor, as required by the gbm function) has `k` levels with R package gbm, I see that the predictions are output as as a vector of length `n*k`. Predicted responses are from:

```
probs.var.multinom <- predict.gbm(gbm.model.multinom, test.data, best.iter.gbm, 
                                  type="response")
```

Note that this is different from the output of a logistic (distribution = "bernoulli") model, where the results are a vector the same length as the number of cases.

How should this be interpreted? Specifically, how can I link the response vector back to the input data set to evaluate the classification?

Comment: Duplicate of SO: [GBM multinomial distribution, how to use predict() to get predicted class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257642/gbm-multinomial-distribution-how-to-use-predict-to-get-predicted-class). I don't have the rep to vote-to-close, please vote yourselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predictions are not returned as a vector, but as an array. If you use: `pred=as.matrix(probs.var.multinom[,,1])`, you'll get a matrix containing the **probabilistic forecasts** of the gbm model. Each forecast (each row) consists of a vector of probabilities for each class (each column) of the output variable. You can then consider the most likely class to be your prediction (if you need a single "best-guess" prediction), compare with the true labels, and then use misclassification rate for each class to evaluate the model, or use metrics such as the Rank Probability Skill Score (RPSS) if you want to use the probabilities associated with the forecasts.